# Have a observable value update on a html file

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

So i have an Observable lets name it `obsVar` in my component.ts file.
I have a button in my appcomponent.html file i.e.

```
<button *ngIf="obsVar | async"> MyButton </button>
```

Now the problem is that if the value for obsVar changes from True to False or viceversa, the change isnt reflected in my page automatically, maybe its something to do with angular and how it saves computation time by not reloading it again

I tried a couple hacks like making another button which would reload the value of this variable by using a original fixed variable

ex:

```
originalVar: Observable<Boolean> = getMyValue();

reloadVar() {
this.obsVar = this.originalVar;
}
```

suppose the original value is false and i have a button which changes the obs variable value to True at the source and also triggers this function(reloadVar) simultaneously, it doesnt change the value because of the time difference for the actual change to propogate.
It works if i click the button 2 or 3 times though.
Any way to do it faster or automate this process so that whenever the obs var changes the change is automatically done on the angular html side too.

Comment: Post the component code which is not working.  Not one of the "hacks".  It is also critical you show how the observable is being obtained, not just a function name like `getMyValue()`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to reassign observable and the reassigning does not update the state?

Comment: @AidHadzic yeah you could say thats one way i am trying to accomplish this. Basically i wanna update the state, if its happens by reassigning or automatically, i am okay with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to have this:

```
isVisible = true;
behaviorSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.isVisible);

public get isVisible$(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.behaviorSubject$.asObservable();
}

public toggle() {
  this.isVisible = !this.isVisible
  this.behaviorSubject$.next(this.isVisible);
}
```

And then in your HTML file:

```
<button *ngIf="isVisible$ | async">MyButton</button>
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Or without Observable:

```
isVisible = true;
public toggle() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible
}

<button *ngIf="isVisible">MyButton</button>
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```